# Entity framework code first t4 template - definition of file names

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to define my own entity framework code first templates for the generation of the model classes from db. I adjusted the model class names according to my needs but I need to define file name of the created files as well (add prefix to class file name). I can't find place where I can do this. I can use some script to rename all files but I would like to avoid to this solution and do it in one step.

Do you have any idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use the ADO.NET Self Tracking Entity Generator T4 template. Per Microsoftt's documentation, you can do something like the following to create multiple files and prefix their names:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
{ 
    fileManager.StartNewFile("file_" + i.ToString() + ".txt"); 
    #> 
        Here is some content for file # <#= i.ToString() #> 
    <# 
}
```

Look under the **The ADO.NET Self Tracking Entity Generator and Multiple Output Files** section of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) MSDN doc for more info.